# jQuery insertAfter adds 2 of the same elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, insertafter

I have this snippet of code that adds a new div to my page.

```
$(document).on('click', '#addLayer', function(e) {

        $('.layer').removeClass('selectedLayer');
        var nl = $('<div class="layer selectedLayer" data-arc="1100">New Layer</div>').insertAfter('.layer');
        nl.arctext({radius: 1100});
        nl.resizable({handles: "nw,sw,se,ne"}).draggable().rotatable({ handles: "s"});
        $('#bead-text').val('New Layer');

    });
```

The first time it is called it works perfect. The second time instead of adding just one div it adds 2 with 1 click. The third time I click it it adds 4 with 1 click. Any idea how I can fix this so it just adds one at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because your selector `.layer` returns multiple elements after your first addition and hence it will add one for each of them, So use `.layer:last`

Try:

```
$('<div class="layer selectedLayer" data-arc="1100">New Layer</div>').insertAfter('.layer:last');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nxSE4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Well, now have two .layers after the first click.  So, when you do

```
$('<div class="layer selectedLayer" data-arc="1100">New Layer</div>').insertAfter('.layer');
```

You are inserting that element per .layer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend first to target the element and then add after it like this:

```
var html = '<div class="layer selectedLayer" data-arc="1100">New Layer</div>';

// select the last element with .layer and put HTML after it
var nl = $('.layer').last().after(html);
```